# Need help on c++ hangman for loop to determine if guess character is in mystery word string

Tags: c++, for-loop

Like the title says, I need help on detecting if player2's guessLetter char is in player1's mysteryWord string.

I want to increment numWrongGuesses only if the guessLetter is not found in mysteryWord and decrement numWrongGuesses if guessLetter is found, no matter how many times. Right now, the program will compare guessLetter to each letter in mysteryWord, and increment numWrongGuesses if they don't match, and decrement numWrongGuesses if they do.

```
//populate string underscores with underscores equal to mysteryword's size initially
for (i = 0; i < mysteryWord.size(); ++i) { underscores.push_back('_'); }

while (numWrongGuesses < 6)
{       
    //displays appropriate noose
    PrintAppropriateNoose(numWrongGuesses); 

    // display underscores string
    for (i = 0; i < mysteryWord.size(); ++i){ cout << underscores.at(i); }
    cout << endl;

    //have user input their guess letter
    cout << player2 << ", what letter do you guess is in " << player1 << "'s mystery word?" << endl; 
    cin >> guessLetter;

    /* if guess letter is in mystery word, decrement numWrongGuesses, replace appropriate underscore in underscores string. If not, increment numWrongGuesses, causing another bodypart to display on noose and same underscores string */
    for (i = 0; i < mysteryWord.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (guessLetter == mysteryWord.at(i))
        {
            numWrongGuesses--;
            underscores.at(i) = guessLetter; 
            cout << "Correct" << endl; //I used this to help debugging
        }
        else
        {
            numWrongGuesses++;
            cout << "incorrect" << endl; //I used this to help debugging
        }
        cout << numWrongGuesses << endl; 
    }
    cout << endl; 
}
```

Comment: Think about it this way.  Your loop has N iterations, where N is the length of the mystery word.  On each iteration, you are incrementing or decrementing `numWrongGuesses`.  That means you could end up with `numWrongGuesses == N` for every single guess the player makes.  Is that what you want?  Can you explain in plain english what you want?

Comment: Oh also, basic tip - magic numbers like "6" are to be avoided, you can declare that as:

`const int MAX_WRONG_GUESSES = 6;` or something

Comment: You could add a "found" state variable, which is initialized to false.. When a match is found, you set it to true, and *break* out of the checking loop. Then *after* the loop you check this "found" state to see if the character were found or not, and perform the corresponding actions.

Comment: By the way, you "have user input their guess letter" *twice* in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: I want to increment numWrongGuesses only if the guessLetter is not found in mysteryWord and decrement numWrongGuesses if guessLetter is found, no matter how many times. Right now, the program will compare guessLetter to each letter in mysteryWord, and increment numWrongGuesses if they don't match, and decrement numWrongGuesses if they do.